# Android/java - How to do that loop wait to do action

Tags: java, android, loops

I try to do app which show elements. Each element should start showing when the before element was hidden. Each element is showing 2 seconds.
Code:

```
public void gameStart()
{
    do
    {
        data = random.nextInt(6) + 1;

                if (data == 1)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }   
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 3)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 4)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 5)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();


                } else if (data == 6)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element6.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();


                }



                id = id + 1;
                text.setText("cos " + id);




    } while (id < 3);
```

All elements are being shown in the same time. And I try add

```
Thread.sleep(2500);
```

But this stoped the action in window. I try add this after code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
    }
 }, 0, 60*1000);
```

But loop wasn't stay. I try do it with `notify()` and `wait()`, but it also don't work.

Don't suggest me to do do next action in `onFinish()` because this must be repeat a lot.
Anybody have another idea?

EDIT 
I also use Handler but it don't work

Comment: This question looks familiar. Didn't you ask this same thing recently? And why in the world would you start a new `CountDownTimer` each time through the `loop`?

Comment: Yes I ask it recently but I try new things and now maybe another people is online and someone mybe know answer

Comment: Because on each time is another condition. data1,data2 etc.

Comment: are you tried with Observable and Observer.
By them, I'm able to control when method is call in real time (such as waiting a thread finish access network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you not to implement this code in the main thread. 
Create an async task, which hides a button and on postExequte calls itself.