# Android - asynctask don't show image when a use get(time)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I try to do app which show elements. Each element should start showing when the before element was hidden. Each element is showing 2 seconds. I try a lot of way:
[Android/java - How to do that loop wait to do action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043207/android-java-how-to-do-that-loop-wait-to-do-action)
And now I try with Asynctask. I find a way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   ImageView image1,image2;
   int id = 0;
   AsyncTask.Status status;
   TextView txt;
   String status1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LongOperation task = new  LongOperation();
    status = task.getStatus();
    status1 = String.valueOf(status);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
    do{
    new LongOperation().execute("");
    id=id+1;
    txt.setText(status1);
    try
    {
        try
        {
            task.get(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }while(id<3);
}



private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txt.setText(status1);       
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        txt.setText("Executed");
        image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}


}
```

(This is a example). App run and end after 7.5 sec (everything ok) but images aren't shown when I start. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating a deadlock situation with your threads. The main UI thread is blocking at the line `task.get()`, which in turn is preventing the AsyncTask from running properly; its `onPreExecute` method is posted onto the UI Thread, and the `doInBackground` doesn't run until `onPreExecute` completes.

Comment: You could make all the waiting happen in the AsyncTask, and then use `onProgressUpdate` (or `onPublishProgress` - I don't remember the exact name), which calls back to the UI thread, whenever you need to change the visibility of a View.

Comment: Okey I find simle way. I get get() to onPostExecute